# Random sampling and i.i.d.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random

Can you help me to clarify the following concepts by stating whether what I have written below is right or wrong?

-**random sampling**: units are drawn from the population with a known probability of extraction.

-**i.i.d. random sampling**: units are drawn from the population independently and identically among each other, e.g. simple random sampling with replacement.

-**example of a random sampling that is not i.i.d.**: simple random sampling without replacement, because draws are not identically neither independently distributed.

Comment: Your third point is not quite correct. In random sampling without replacement, the draws _are_ identically distributed but they are not independent.  Read [this answer of mine on stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17874/6633) for a simple illustration.